# Setting exponential notation in log axes ticks - Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm plotting data in logarithmic scale using *semilogx*, and letting Matlab mark the axes with auto ticks and tick labels.

This generally works well, except when the range does not include a power of ten. In these cases, I get tick marks like: 10^2.2    10^2.3    10^2.4    ...
 Which are really uncomfortable to read and interpret!
[image]

Is there a way to force the tick labels to correct exponential notation (ie 150 x 10^2) ?

(hardcoding the labels isn't an option because axes range changes dynamically)

Comment: i'll add an image illustrating the problem as soon as I get to 10 reputation ;)

Comment: There you go! Post the image :)

Comment: couple of questions... will the notation required change or will the plot always require notation in the form 150x10^something? Is the range changing dynamically, due resizing and zooming etc or replotting different data?

Comment: @RTL yes, i'd like to have this type of notation always. Range is changing because of different data. I found a workaround, see my answer below. Other ideas are welcome though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it using sprintf:

```
xt = get(gca,'xtick')
xt_label = sprintf('%.2e|',xt)
set(gca,'xticklabel',xt_label)
```

Now I get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the tick labels back to the actual values, rather than the exponential labels, with something like:

```
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', get(gca,'XTick'))
```

This just uses the actual values at which each XTick appears as the legend for that XTick.  You end up with odd numbers (because they will correspond to the uniformly-log-spaced values), but at least they will be readable.

Comment: thanks dpwe, this produces readable labels indeed, but with large numbers (in the 1e6 or 1e7 range) they aren't very neat.. see my other answer for the solution I found